# Calculate $S =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Calculate $S =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$. I know I posted this question already but I want a more detailed answer. For example, how you got from one step to another using the partial fraction formula. Thanks!

Comment: Much better to ask in your original question

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {1}{k(k+1)(k+2)} = \left( \frac {1}{k} - \frac {1}{k+1}\right) \frac {1}{k+2} = \frac {1}{k(k+2)} -  \frac {1}{(k+1)(k+2)}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac {1}{k} - \frac {1}{k+2} \right) - \left( \frac {1}{k+1} - \frac {1}{k+2} \right)$